# Parse multiple html files and insert content into wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to parse 5000 plus files, get different tags content and store data into wordpress(insert as a post). I am using DOM method, but in this way I need to parse single file every time. I want to run script, that parse all files from specific folder and store data into database.

```
<?php
// Include DOM Library File
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from file
$html = file_get_html('include/one.asp');

// Find H1
foreach($html->find('h1') as $element) 
   echo $element;

// Find all post content 
foreach($html->find('p') as $element) 
   echo $element;
```

Files structure same, Below I also share some files link.

> http://onfleek.dabdemo.com/include/one.asp
>
> http://onfleek.dabdemo.com/include/two.asp

Any help??

Comment: What is "file structure same"? What is the file structure? I think this will be easy to do. You just need to recursively traverse the file structure. But what have you tried?

Comment: @franklin ... file structure mean: all files have same tags and div. I am using DOM Parser method for this. But in this way I parse only one file at a time not at all but I want: start script, they parse all files and insert data into database.